Identify weird contraption on a WWII American Cruiser
This the USS Pensacola (CA-24) (Wikipedia) as it appears in the online game "World of Warships".

The model is, I believe, quite accurate.
I am wondering what this weird contraption is, located at the center line of the ship and about 1/4 of the way from the stern:
Port side view

Starboard view

It looks like the guts of a cannon, minus the barrel, but I have no idea why such a thing would be there.
Does anyone know what this is?

IDK but a device somewhat similar to a harpoon cannon to fire throwing lines at other ships for transfers at sea?

@GregLocock this is a good hypothesis; there are two slight problems I see with it: 1. The device is somewhat hidden between two boxes that seem to be about one story high each, so it has reduced visibility to the sea.  2. The device does not seem capable of rotating about its vertical axis.  Anyway, if we could find how such devices are called, then we could find other photos to verify whether that is in fact what it is.

@GregLocock as it turns out, what you are referring to is called a Line Thrower for Underway Replenishment but I have been unable to find any reference in these sources to any similar-looking device.

Pensacola class cruiser had a bracketing and crane system to store and launch small planes. 
Though biplanes were deemed obsolete by WWII they stayed in service because short takeoff length (cause double wing surface area and easy repair engines) and could be launched and recovered by large ships that weren't carriers. Battleships typically carried one and largest carried two
They also had bracket/launch systems for boats. 


This is all true; and the biplane, the catapults, and the cranes are all visible on the ship model, but they are located in the middle of the ship, between the two chimneys. The device that I am talking about is located between the two superstructures right aft of the aft chimney, and it does not look like it has anything to do with the plane.

It appears that the Pensacola underwent various modifications throughout its lifetime. The version with the 3 boats stacked near the center-line of the ship (shown by the diagram above) seems to be an early one.  In later modifications, these boats were removed or moved elsewhere. The contraption I am talking about was apparently placed there where the middle boat used to be.
